# "destination-out"-like blending behavior using CSS?

Tags: html, css, transparency, alpha, masking

I have an image. I have a second graphical element ontop of this image, whose alpha I want to use to "hide" parts of the image below it, while the top element itself isn't shown.

Something along the lines of

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"
```

This top element will change transparency and shape live, so prerendering everything onto a seperate canvas won't be an option.

I was thinking of "multiply" but it didn't do what I expected it to. I thought if I put the alpha of the top layer to "0", that would be multiplied with the layer below, also making it transparent. (I was sad it didn't work)

**Is there someway to "hack" this using the existing CSS blending modes (or any other method)?**

Comment: Blend? Like filter: blur in CSS 3?

Comment: Like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes

Comment: Simplest way is to use transparent overlay. More complex operations you can do in webgl even mobile browsers support it, not all, but if quality matters... Consider if effect is worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider `mask-image` (however, note that currently there's no support for this on IE / Edge):

```css
img {
  -webkit-mask-image: url(http://www.lordtennyson.ca/uploads/1/2/4/2/12421219/paw_print_small.png);
  mask-image: url(http://www.lordtennyson.ca/uploads/1/2/4/2/12421219/paw_print_small.png);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.dizzydi.com/uploads/6/5/6/5/65656887/6168555.jpg" />
```